# overload with typedef gives an error

Tags: c++, overloading

Consider the following types:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned long long      usize_t;
typedef unsigned __int16        uword_t;
typedef uword_t                 clockval_t;     // time without seconds in format HHMM

std::string toString(clockval_t nClock)
{
    return std::to_string((usize_t)nClock/100) + ":" + std::to_string((usize_t)nClock % 100);
}

std::string toString(uword_t nValue)
{
    return std::to_string((usize_t)nValue);
}

void test(void)
{
    uword_t val = 1;
    clockval_t time = 1023; // 10:23

    std::cout << "Value: " << toString(val);
    std::cout << "time: " << toString(time);
}
```

Now when I try to compile this, I get an error from the compiler telling me that the `std::string toString(clockval_t)` already has a body. I understand why this happens of course, because the typedef is just an alias for `uword_t`.

AFAIK the only solutions are to provide a separate method:

```
std::string toClockString(clockval_t);
```

or make it an object:

```
class clockval ...
```

Is this correct or is there some other way to make the compiler choose the correct overload?

Comment: Ah, the joys of the C type system!

Comment: Yeah, it's IMO a bit weak, because the whole point of typedefs is to create new types, so the compiler should be able to properly distinguish them to make it consistent. I guess there is some backward compatibillity issue involved though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if there were a way to make compiler choose correct version, do you realize how it would be error-prone? Luckily, there is no such way  because `typedef` creates alias and nothing more.

I suggest that you convert it into class. If you provide proper constructor and conversion operator then you even don't need to change parts of code which make use of `clockval_t`:

```
class clockval_t {
public:
  clockval_t(uword_t aValue) : value(aValue) {}
  operator uword_t() const { return value; }

private:
  uword_t value;
};

...

clockval_t time = 1023; // works fine
std::cout << time << std::endl; // works fine
std::cout << (time / 10) << std::endl; // works fine
```

Comment: THANKS! This is definitely the best answer. :) I checked the machine code to make sure that there is no unneccessary overhead as opposed to a simple word (which would have been my major concern against an object) and this behaves exactly like a `word` while having the benefits of the type. :)

Comment: This has a drawback that you are losing all arithmetic operations on the clockval_t. You would need to redefine every operator in the class (if needed).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct or is there some other way to make the compiler choose the correct overload?

Yes you're correct, you can't overload on `typedef` since it's simply an alias.  As you rightly suggest, either rename the function or create a new type with `class`.  Adding a *fake* parameter simply to change the function signature is usually a bad idea, renaming is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of typedef is defined in the standard as (7.1.3 The typedef specifier):

> Within the scope of its declaration, a typedef-name is syntactically equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated with the identifier (...). A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type. A typedef-name does
>   not introduce a new type (...).

Therefore the two functions are indeed ambiguous in regard to the type of input parameter. You need to distinguish the type (e.g. by using different type, e.g. a class or enum) or perhaps add a second parameter (maybe with a default value) indicating which kind type exactly is being passed in.

Link to original answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254473/in-which-stage-of-compilation-is-typedef-resolved-by-the-compiler

Comment: I like this answer because of the citation, but I agree with the accepted answer, that adding a fake parameter is not a good idea, and is essentially very similar to creating a specific function name.